# Using @Query in spring data jpa results in Object class as return type

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

As shown in the code below, I have a flightRepository that has a querySearchFormFlights method.When I want to see its elements in the test class, to my surprise, all of them are Object type in the output, not the Flight type! Why is it like this?

```
@Repository
public interface FlightRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Flight,Integer> {
    @Query("select f.flightId,f.fromAirport,f.toAirport,f.departure,f.arrival from Flight f")
    Page<Flight> querySearchFormFlights(PageRequest request);
}
```

test class

```
@SpringBootTest
class AirportApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private FlightRepository flightRepository;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        List<Flight> flights=flightRepository.querySearchFormFlights(PageRequest.of(0,20)).getContent();
    }
}
```

output:

```
[[Ljava.lang.Object;@4ed7db72, [Ljava.lang.Object;@7018636a, [Ljava.lang.Object;@3e866323, [Ljava.lang.Object;@73624529, [Ljava.lang.Object;@31e1c7c, [Ljava.lang.Object;@30ae3c46, [Ljava.lang.Object;@3dbcde0b, [Ljava.lang.Object;@5c168f98, [Ljava.lang.Object;@2f98859a, [Ljava.lang.Object;@6e95c023]
```

Comment: @dariosicily I did it but it did not work!

Comment: You won't get the Flight objects with your query. Try this one: select f from Flight f

Comment: @Mar-Z Well, if I do it like this, it will consume too much memory due to having many joins. Is there no way to select some columns?

Comment: As answered by @Daniel you can define a projection of the entity and use it in the repository method. (Even without a specific query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current query you actually define another view of entity to be loaded (as not all fields are included). And this is considered not to be an initial entity as actually has a difference in fields (even if it is a subset of fields).

If you need to load only some particular fields from your objects and not the whole object - Spring Data provides such functionality as 'Projection' to do so.

It allows to define an interface with only needed fields and load only those fields.

[Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections) with projection examples

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer by @Daniel here code snippets using projection interface:

Projection interface:

```
public interface FlightView {
    String getFlightId();
    String getFromAirport();
    String getToAirport();
    String getDeparture();
    String getArrival();
}
```

Usage in repository:

```
@Repository
public interface FlightRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Flight,Integer> {
    Page<FlightView> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```